nginx, gunicorn & django on amazon lightsail, what is the hostname of the ip address?
I deployed a Django application to Amazon Lightsail VPS, and it works as expected when I access it by the domain name xxxxx.com, However, if I tried to access it by the IP address, it gave an error:
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'ec2-MY-IP-ADDR-Here.compute-1.amazonaws.com'. 
You may need to add 'ec2-MY-IP-ADDR-Here.compute-1.amazonaws.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
DisallowedHost at /

Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'ec2-MY-IP-ADDR-Here.compute-1.amazonaws.com'. 
You may need to add 'ec2-MY-IP-ADDR-Here.compute-1.amazonaws.com' to  ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://ec2-MY-IP-ADDR-Here.compute-1.amazonaws.com/`

Of course, the MY-IP-ADDR-Here is my actual IP address number.
I wander:

Why did the lightsail change the url from 'MY.IP.Addr.Here' to ec2-MY-IP-ADDR-Here.compute-1.amazonaws.com/?
Why did the nginx proxy this request to Django? I expected it to discard the request.
Is it safe to add the ec2-MY-IP-ADDR-Here.compute-1.amazonaws.com to my allowed hosts?
Is it a good idea to remove MY-IP-ADDR-Here from my'settings.py`?

The following are the related configuration parameters:
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite
   
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xxxxx.com MY.IP.ADDr.Here;
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;        
        }
      }
 # many lines created  hy certbot  
 #
`# I added the following block to tell nginx to discard any request that doesn't match the xxxxx.com MY.IP.ADDr.Here;
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/deployment/checklist/#allowed-hosts`

 server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    return 444;
  }

myproject/settings.py
 ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["xxxxx.com", "MY-IP-ADDR-Here"]


I dont suggest to add it to ALLOWED_HOST this way


It is Not suggest to add it to ALLOWED_HOST this way as it is unsafe.

Add it to env variables if at all it is nesseccary for you to access the page using ipaddress else dont do that.


